# Which Bansuri Fingering Chart to use with Practicing Saptak (both Beginners and Experienced)

Tags: practice, fingering, indian-classical, bansuri

I totally appreciate the nuances of Bansuri notation. And I am starting to notice subtle differences when practicing half-notes (i.e. Komal)

Is it best practice to use simple Bansuri fingering chart for practicing Saptak, i.e. `Sa Re Ga Ma PA DHA NI SA`, ***regardless of experience level***?

OR

Should all Bansuri musicians ***strive to follow advanced Bansuri fingering chart*** when practicing Saptak, including those who started practice 2 to 3 months ago.

#### Simple Bansuri Fingering Chart

[image]

#### Advanced Bansuri Fingering Chart

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting out you should use Saptak, but when you become better, you should use the advanced fingering chart as it includes sharps and flats(they are very important). The advanced fingering chart is pretty hard to play in the start, but after a few months of practice, it becomes easier.

Comment: Ah, you mean use simple fingering chart in beginning. Yesterday I tried out the advanced fingering chart when practicing the Saptak. Going from `Ma` to `PA` was actually simpler (because I'm covering 5 holes instead of 6). However, going from `PA` to `DHA` is harder because you go from covering bottom 5 holes to covering top 5 holes.